# I have created a python library and importing one python file from other in that file but I get import error?

Tags: python

[image]

I am trying to import lr_finder.py inside training.py as
`from lr_finder import LRFinder`, LRFinder is class inside lr_finder. 
But I get import error for lr_finder.py

Comment: Never add `.py` to your imports

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from .lr_finder import LRFinder
```

Also have a [read](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) about absolute vs relative imports.